# Netsuite search select custom field

Tags: search, soap, netsuite, suitetalk

I am developing an app based on netsuite suitetalk api for webservices, specifically for search. I am able to search for custom multiselectfield  using the soap api. Multiselect internalId is 16. Sample below

```
 <core:customField xsi:type="core:SearchMultiSelectCustomField" internalId="16" operator="anyOf">
           <core:searchValue internalId="1">
  </core:customField>
```

However when I use the same api, with internalId 5690, it says it is not valid, this is the soap api. 5690 represents a select custom field as opposed to a multi select custom field

```
 <core:customField xsi:type="core:SearchMultiSelectCustomField" internalId="5690" operator="anyOf">
           <core:searchValue internalId="1">
  </core:customField>
```

This is the result

```
<platformCore:status isSuccess="false">
                   <platformCore:statusDetail type="ERROR">
                      <platformCore:code>INVALID_SEARCH_FIELD_OBJ</platformCore:code>
                      <platformCore:message>custentity41 is not a valid search custom field</platformCore:message>
                   </platformCore:statusDetail>
                </platformCore:status>
             </platformCore:searchResult>
```

what is the operation used to search custom selectfield in netsuite via soap. Is it exposed ? I can do this from netsuite UI. But not finding a way to do it from soap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always use SuiteScript inside NetSuite, so I'm not 100% on this...  But, I'd say the issue is that you are looking for "core:SearchMultiSelectCustomField" on the Select call.  Shouldn't that be changed to "core:SearchSelectCustomField" instead?

Comment: I think this is the field SearchCustomFieldList. Looking at the schema here. https://webservices.na0.netsuite.com/xsd/platform/v2018_2_0/core.xsd

Comment: SearchSelectCustomField doesn't exist. Have checked the schema

Comment: Interesting.  I found it referenced in the docs, previously.  Maybe they removed it.?

Answer (score 0):

SearchMultiSelectCustomField type works for SelectCustomField as well. Maybe my soap request was constructed wrong. Or something else. Weird. Basically this works

```
<core:customField xsi:type="core:SearchMultiSelectCustomField" internalId="5690" operator="anyOf">
       <core:searchValue internalId="1"/>
     </core:customField>
```

where 5690 is a selectcustomfield ref